# Expired Certificate In Exchange

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I manage a single Exchange 2013 server for a small business. The server has a valid SSL cert installed for the main domain and all sub-domains. All PCs on the domain work without issue. The problem is that there is a computer off-site. Outlook on this computer continually receives an older, expired certificate when trying to configure email. I cannot find this certificate anywhere on the server, and I am unsure why it is only handed out to a computer that is not part of the domain. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What the device is going through the domain to the outside of the domain? 
A Device likes the load balancer, If you have a load balancer, the issue may be caused by the certificate in the device.

Can you tell me the detailed information about your environment?

In addition, expired certificates will appear in many places. During the Autodiscover process, many URLs will be queried, and the expired certificate may exist on one of these URLs.
I found a similar [case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f3ac004-9889-4431-b612-d36f64e00827/exchange-2010-certificate-issue?forum=exchange2010) that might be helpful to you.

Comment: It's a single server... both domain controller and exchange server. Set up before we started doing the IT work. Only 10 users so it works this way without issues. Server 2012 R2. Using the remote connectivity analyzer, it seems to be pulling the cert when querying contoso.com/Autodiscover versus mail.contoso.com/Autodiscover. I'm trying to figure out now how to either redirect to mail.contoso.com/Autodiscover or return a 404 for the first URL (read that somewhere on the internet). Does that sound like I am on the right track?

Comment: You can refer to this article about autodiscover 404 errors. https://support.episerver.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007520192-Autodiscover-404-errors

Comment: Any updates? Has the issue been solved?

Comment: No, I've actually given up. The issue still happens, and non-domain users get a warning each time they open Outlook. I've spent hours searching for this mystery cert but don't know what else to do.

Comment: There are two methods for you to find certificate:
Use powershell to find out certificates (use powershell and .net to find expired certificate)
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-and-net-to-find-expired-certificates/
in addition, certutil.exe is the main tool to manage certificates.
 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc732443(v=ws.11)
Hope this help.